# Efficiently computing difference matrix based on Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have a dataframe, and I am trying to find the numeric difference between different rows within one column (series), resulting in a square matrix with both dimensions equal to the length of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[200, 2],[100,2], [1000,10], [600,5], [50,1]],
                  columns=['Sales','Total prods'])
print(df['Sales'])
```

```
0     200
1     100
2    1000
3     600
4      50
Name: Sales, dtype: int64
```

I have written this function:

```
def numerical_scoring(col_name, result_ints):
    matrix_df = np.zeros(shape=(len(result_ints), len(result_ints)))
    for index_x, row_x in result_ints[[col_name]].iterrows(): 
        for index_y, row_y in result_ints[[col_name]].iterrows():
            if index_x == index_y:
                matrix_df[index_x, index_y] = 1
            else: 
                matrix_df[index_x, index_y] = abs(row_x[0] - row_y[0])
                
    return matrix_df  

print(numerical_scoring('Sales', df))
```

```
[[  1. 100. 800. 400. 150.]
 [100.   1. 900. 500.  50.]
 [800. 900.   1. 400. 950.]
 [400. 500. 400.   1. 550.]
 [150.  50. 950. 550.   1.]]
```

This code works for small dataframes, but when the dataframe grows to millions of records, this is taking a long time to complete. Is there a more efficient way of transforming the data?

Comment: Could you show an example of your input and output?

Comment: Running code will give you the results.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Shubham Sharma's answer is more elegant and efficient, and I recommend it. However, I'm leaving this here because you're bound to encounter other situations where you *do* have to implement your own algorithm, and it's good to understand how to do so more efficiently.

---

There are several things that can be improved here.

- Your function constructs a single-column dataframe and then iterates over its rows with `result_ints[[col_name]].iterrows()`. It would be simpler to work with the column/series itself and iterate over its *items*, with `result_ints[col_name].iteritems()`.
- But your function only needs to operate on a single column, which is a [Pandas series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html). So we can just pass that as the argument, and not even worry about the dataframe.
- Your data is all integers, so there's no need for your result matrix to use float values.
- And here's the big one: **You're duplicating a lot of work.** Your result matrix is symmetrical along the diagonal, so you're currently doing identical calculations twice.

Here's a version that skips some unnecessary work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def numerical_scoring(series):
    length = len(series)
    matrix = np.zeros(shape=(length, length), dtype=int)
    
    # Set the diagonal cells to 1
    for i in range(length):
        matrix[i, i] = 1
    
    # Iterate through the items...
    for i, i_val in series.iteritems():
        # For each item, iterate only through the items after it.
        for j, j_val in series[i + 1:].iteritems():
            # Set both identical cells simulataneously.
            matrix[i, j] = matrix[j, i] = abs(i_val - j_val)
    
    return matrix

df = pd.DataFrame([[200, 2],[100,2], [1000,10], [600,5], [50,1]],
                  columns=['Sales','Total prods'])
print(numerical_scoring(df['Sales']))
```

```
[[  1 100 800 400 150]
 [100   1 900 500  50]
 [800 900   1 400 950]
 [400 500 400   1 550]
 [150  50 950 550   1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) to calculate the pairwise distances then using [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) convert the pairwise distance vector to square matrix, finally update the diagonal values of square matrix to `1`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

arr = squareform(pdist(df[['Sales']]))
arr[np.diag_indices(len(arr))] = 1
```

Result:

```
array([[  1., 100., 800., 400., 150.],
       [100.,   1., 900., 500.,  50.],
       [800., 900.,   1., 400., 950.],
       [400., 500., 400.,   1., 550.],
       [150.,  50., 950., 550.,   1.]])
```

Comment: @khb If this solution has answered your question then you may accept/upvote the answer .  Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)